# Walkthrough of constituent parts of D3 Hierarchical Edge Bundling example

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization, bundle-layout

I would love to understand and recreate a similar version of this object:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

This is an example - but I cannot workout how it works or where the code for it lies?

Can somebody either break the sample apart for me into its constituent parts (js, html, css) which would allow me to navigate and reverse engineer how it works, or point me at an appropriate tutorial explaining that sample?

Cheers

Comment: What is wrong with **View page source** from your browser? The code is all there...

Comment: I feel I am missing something when copying that and running on my server it results in a completely blank page. I'm not convinced view page source is showing all the code either probably due to frames.

Comment: View source will have the complete HTML but you need to dereference any links to get the complete code.  So you'll need to put style.css, d3/d3.js, d3/d3.layout.js and packages.js on your server also.

Comment: I guess you will miss the data source of course. The JavaScript is loading `"flare-imports.json"`. So simply doing a Copy and Paste wont do. Rather use the code as a guideline and implement step by step by yourself. If you get a blank page, do you get errors from the console? Have a closer look at the diagnostic tools from your browser. (e.g. Chrome: Ctrl-Shift-i)

Comment: Did you start with this? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1044242

Comment: Check the console, if there are any error messages. Make sure you download and then include all the script, css and data(flare.json) files.